# What strategy for encrypting web.config sections should I use?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, encryption, web-config

I want to add automated encryption of some sections of web.config with following requirements:

1. It should be done automatically every time application is started (I don't want to do it manually using `aspnet_regiis` after each config edit)
2. It should automatically happen only on production environment (I need to see my values on my machine)

It's not a problem to find the code for it, my question is where to put it and how to make sure it's not executed on my localhost?
I tried to put it to Global.asax but I get `Request is not available in this context` exception there.

Thanks.

Comment: Web.config is used to determine, amongst other things, what version of .Net should execute - thus you can't encrypt the _whole_ file and decrypt it from within .Net as by then it's too late. Encrypting certain sections of the file is a different matter entirely...

Comment: Encrypting values **after** application starts sounds like very interesting approach to security... Why not to keep it plain text all the time than?

Comment: If you already have the plaintext on the production server, encrypting it later does very little good.

Comment: @Basic, I don't want to encrypt all file, I meant sections, sorry it's not obvious.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Slaks, we have had a hacking attack recently, they got access to our file system, so we don't want our db passwords to be there as simple text anymore. I think it's a good enough reason.

Comment: I believe the misunderstanding is that the question says you want to _encrypt_ not _decrypt_. If you're encrypting, you already have it in plaintext on your server.

Comment: @Basic, yes I want to encrypt. Suppose I add/update a connection string manually, after that application restarts and the connectionStrings section is encrypted so db usenames/passwords don't sit as plain text there anymore. I'm sorry, I'm quite new to it, but I thought it should be obvious.

Comment: The difficult part is decrypting your web.config file on your production server to modify the connection string. You would have to manually decrypt the string (or write code in your app) to decrypt it and then modify it again. If somebody forgets to re-encrypt, you're in trouble. That's why I recommend doing it as part of the deployment process. Use web.config transforms to keep your production environment safe, then encrypt after it is pushed up. This can be scripted.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend setting this up as part of your deployment process.

Calling the encryption every time the application starts isn't a good idea because the ASP.Net App Pool will recycle itself from time to time, and that could cause problems.

Depending on your deployment process, you can do it through a batch file, powershell script, but it will need to be run on your production machine in question.

Comment: I _believe_ the OP meant that web.config should be _decrypted_ every time the app starts (seems to make more sense)

Comment: If you're using the basic web.config encryption model provided by aspnet_regiis, it'll auto decrypt the web.config whenever it needs to pull a value from it. However, if we're talking about the ENTIRE web.config, that might be a little different.

Comment: @Dillie-O what problems can I have with it? I know about machineKey, I'm going to use permanent one. I didn't want to encrypt entire file, I updated the question. And I didn't want to do it manually every time if I can just add those 5 lines of code which will take care about it for me.

Comment: Are you attempting to encrypt the entire web.config or just parts. The connection strings and appsettings should run without a problem. I'm unfamiliar with other means of encrypting the entire file.

Comment: Sections not entire file, I mentioned it in my previos comment and updated the question.